# how to wait till the response is received from redis in node?

Tags: node.js, redis

I am new to node and redis.I am using redis in my node application.I want to retreive 
data from redis in a synchronous fashion.Here is what I tried.

```
var redis = require("redis"),
client = redis.createClient();

client.set('key',10,redis.print);

function getfn1(key){
    client.get(key,function(err,reply){
        if(err){
            console.log('Response from getfn1:-');
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Response from getfn1:-');
        console.log(reply);
    });
}

async function getfn2(key){
    let response = await client.get(key);
    console.log('Response from getfn2:-');
    console.log(response);
}
console.log('1');
getfn1('key');
console.log('2');
getfn2('key');
console.log('3');
```

The result is as follows:

```
1
2
3
Response from getfn2:-
false
Response from getfn1:-
10
```

As you can see I am trying to wait for the result from redis using async and  await in getfn2() but I get a response of 'false' instead of the original response of 10.It would be better if you suggested a method of waiting for data from redis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `async/await` syntax is meant to be used with Promises, but the redis module does not return Promises by default.

If you want to use Promises, this is what the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#promises) says to do:

> You can also use node_redis with promises by promisifying node_redis
>   with bluebird as in:
>
> ```
> var redis = require('redis');
> bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
> bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.Multi.prototype);
> ```
>
> It'll add a Async to all
>   node_redis functions (e.g. return client.getAsync().then())
>
> ```
> // We expect a value 'foo': 'bar' to be present
> // So instead of writing client.get('foo', cb); you have to write:
> return client.getAsync('foo').then(function(res) {
>   console.log(res); // => 'bar'
> });
> ```

Your `getfn2` function would then become:

```
async function getfn2(key){
  let response = await client.getAsync(key);
  console.log('Response from getfn2:-');
  console.log(response);
}
```